# Symfony Doctrine Extensions not showing parent child list

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, doctrine-extensions

I'm having issue with parent-child list view in symfony gedmo doctrine extensions.
My list is showing everything in the same level and I don't know how to fix it.
I've tried to use `datagridvalues` to sort by `lft`field but it is not working.

My `category.orm.yml` file

```
Application\AdminBundle\Entity\Category:
  type: entity
  table: Category
  gedmo:
    tree:
      type: nested
  id:
    id:
      type: integer
      generator:
        strategy: AUTO
  fields:
    name:
      type: string
      length: 255
    image_url:
      type: string
      length: 255  
    slug:
      type: string
      nullable: false
      unique: true

    lft:
      type: integer
      gedmo:
        - treeLeft
    rgt:
      type: integer
      gedmo:
        - treeRight
    root:
      type: integer
      gedmo:
        - treeRoot
    lvl:
      type: integer
      gedmo:
        - treeLevel

  oneToMany:
    children:
      targetEntity: Category
      mappedBy: parent
  manyToOne:
    parent:
      targetEntity: Category
      inversedBy: children
      gedmo:
        - treeParent
      joinColumns:
        Category_id:
          referencedColumnName: id
  lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

And My configureListFields method:

```
protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
{

    $listMapper
    ->add('id')
    ->add('name')
    ->add('slug')
    ;
}
```

My list view looks like in image [image: List view]

Answer (score 0):

I was fighting with this too long ;)

I found in some codeproject's article that sonata admin is not supporting tree structures rendering (article was from 2012 so maybe something changed).
Anyway my solution is preety simple

In my `category.php` i've added

```
public function __toString()
{
    $prefix = '';
    for ($i=1; $i<= $this->lvl; $i++){
        $prefix .= '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';
    }
    return $prefix . $this->name;
}

public function getLaveledTitle()
{
    return (string)$this;
}
```

and in `CategoryController.php` in `configureListFields` method i've changed `name` field to

```
    $listMapper
     //if you will not add 'html' as field type `&nbsp` will not be parsed as html
    ->add('laveled_title', 'html', array(
            'strip' => true,
            'label' => 'Category Name'
    ))
    ;
```